# Pokémon Type Advantage Modifiers

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

I'm looking for a list of any item, move, ability, etc. that would *modify* the standard type advantages in Pokémon up to and including ORAS for Nintendo 3DS.

**For example:**
Typically, Bronzong (Steel and Psychic type) would be weak to Ground type attacks since Ground is super effective against Steel, and Psychic is neither weak or strong to Ground. However, if Bronzong has the Levitate ability, he becomes completely immune to all Ground attacks.

If the opposing Pokémon uses the move Smack Down, however, this allows Bronzong to be hit by Ground-type moves again.

I'm working on a personal project to create an applet to calculate many things Pokémon, including potential type advantages in many different situations.

Can anyone enumerate these for me?

Comment: Ooh, fun. I'm going to post what I know as a community wiki- I think that's the best way to handle this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Moves

### Immunity Changing

- *Foresight* - Removes target Ghost-type Pokémon's immunity to Fighting-type and Normal-type attacks
- *Gravity* - Field effect; negates the Ground-type immunity from the Flying type, the Levitate Ability, or the Air Balloon item for all Pokémon while in effect.
- *Ingrain* - Negates the user's Ground-type immunity while in effect, prevents Magnet Rise and Telekinesis.
- *Magnet Rise* - User becomes immune to Ground-type moves for 5 turns
- *Miracle Eye* - Removes target Dark-type Pokémon's immunity to Psychic-type attacks
- *Odor Sleuth* - Removes target Ghost-type Pokémon's immunity to Fighting-type and Normal-type attacks
- *Smack down* - Negates the Ground-type immunity from the Flying type, Levitate, or other moves until the target is switched out.
- *Telekinesis* - Target becomes immune to Ground-type attacks for three turns.
- *Thousand Arrows* - Hits airborne targets (applies effect of Smack Down) despite being a Ground-type move. This move exists within the coding of the game but cannot be obtained in-game although it's possible that Game Freak will subsequently release it at an event.

### Effectiveness Changing

- *Water Sport* - Reduces the base power of Fire-type moves by 67% on both sides in battle. The effects last for 5 turns.
- *Mud Sport* - Reduces the base power of Electric-type moves by 67% on both sides in battle. The effects last for 5 turns.

### Pokemon Type Changing

- *Camouflage* - Changes the user's type to a type corresponding to the battlefield terrain
- *Conversion* - Changes the user's current type to match the type of the first of the user's moves
- *Conversion 2* - Randomly change the user's current type to a type that either resists or is immune to the type of the move last used by the target
- *Forest's Curse* - Adds Grass typing to target Pokemon (dual-type Pokemon gain a third type)
- *Reflect Type* - Changes the user's type to match the type or types of the target
- *Roost* - User loses the Flying type (if they have it) until the end of the turn. Pure Flying-types gain the Normal type during this time.
- *Soak* - Changes the target's type to pure Water
- *Trick-or-Treat* - Adds Ghost typing to target Pokemon. (dual-type Pokemon gain a third type)

### Move Type Changing

- *Electrify* - Changes the target's move Electric-type for that turn
- *Ion Deluge* - All Normal-type moves used by any Pokémon on the field become Electric-type for the remainder of the current turn

### Ability Changing/Suppression

- *Entrainment* - Changes the target's Ability to match the user's while it remains in battle.
- *Gastro Acid* - Suppresses the target's ability while it remains in battle.
- *Role Play* - Replaces the user's Ability with the target's Ability
- *Simple Beam* - Switches target's ability to Simple while it remains in battle.
- *Skill Swap* -  Exchange the Abilities of the user and the target
- *Worry Seed* - Switches target's ability to Insomnia while it remains in battle.

## Abilities

### Resistance/Immunity Changing

- *Delta Stream* - Causes a unique Weather effect that makes it so no moves are super-effective against the Flying type.
- *Desolate Land* - Causes damage-dealing Water-type moves to fail
- *Dry Skin* - 25% more damage from Fire-type moves, Water-type moves are negated and instead heal 1/4 the Pokémon's max HP.
- *Flash Fire* - Immune to Fire-type moves.
- *Heatproof* - Halves damage from Fire-type moves.
- *Levitate* - Immune to Ground-type moves.
- *Lightning Rod* - Immune to Electric-type moves.
- *Motor Drive* - Immune to Electric-Type moves.
- *Heavy Rain* - Causes damage-dealing Fire-type moves to fail
- *Sap Sipper* - Immune to Grass-type moves.
- *Scrappy* - Allows Pokemon to hit Ghost types with Normal/Fighting-type moves.
- *Storm Drain* - Immune to Water-type moves.
- *Thick Fat* - Halves damage from Fire-type and Ice-type moves.
- *Tinted Lens* - Doubles the power of "not very effective" moves.
- *Volt Absorb* - Heal from Electric-type moves.
- *Water Absorb* - Heal from Water-type moves.
- *Wonder Guard* - Immune to all moves that are not super-effective.

### Pokemon Type Changing

- *Color Change* - Causes Pokémon with this Ability type to change to the type of the move that it was hit by
- *Multitype* - Changes the type of the Pokémon with this Ability depending on the Plate equipped
- *Protean* - Causes Pokémon with this Ability to change type to be the same type as the move it is using

### Move Type Changing

- *Aerilate* - Causes the Pokemon's Normal type moves to become Flying type.
- *Normalize* - Causes the Pokemon's moves to become Normal type. This may allow it to bypass some weaknesses/immunities, while introducing others.
- *Pixilate* - Causes the Pokemon's Normal type moves to become Fairy type.
- *Refrigerate* - Causes the Pokemon's Normal type moves to become Ice-type

### Ability Suppression

- *Mold Breaker* - Ignores effects of Abilities that would affect the damage or effects of its moves.
- *Teravolt* - Ignores effects of Abilities that would affect the damage or effects of its moves.
- *Turboblaze* - Ignores effects of Abilities that would affect the damage or effects of its moves.
- *Trace* - Copies opponent's ability

## Items

### Held Items

- *Ring Target* - Holder loses all type immunities.
- *Air Balloon* - Holder is immune to Ground-type moves (until hit, when the balloon will pop)
- *Iron Ball* - Negates holder's Ground-type immunity from the Flying type or Levitate ability, prevents Telekinesis and Magnet Rise.

### Berries (Negate super-effective bonus once)

- *Occa Berry* -   Decreases damage taken by the holder from a supereffective Fire-type move
- *Passho Berry* - Decreases damage taken by the holder from a supereffective Water-type move
- *Wacan Berry* -  Decreases damage taken by the holder from a supereffective Electric-type move
- *Rindo Berry* -  Decreases damage taken by the holder from a supereffective Grass-type move
- *Yache Berry* -  Decreases damage taken by the holder from a supereffective Ice-type move
- *Chople Berry* - Decreases damage taken by the holder from a supereffective Fighting-type move
- *Kebia Berry* -  Decreases damage taken by the holder from a supereffective Poison-type move
- *Shuca Berry* -  Decreases damage taken by the holder from a supereffective Ground-type move
- *Coba Berry* -   Decreases damage taken by the holder from a supereffective Flying-type move
- *Payapa Berry* - Decreases damage taken by the holder from a supereffective Psychic-type move
- *Tanga Berry* -  Decreases damage taken by the holder from a supereffective Bug-type move
- *Charti Berry* - Decreases damage taken by the holder from a supereffective Rock-type move
- *Kasib Berry* -  Decreases damage taken by the holder from a supereffective Ghost-type move
- *Haban Berry* -  Decreases damage taken by the holder from a supereffective Dragon-type move
- *Colbur Berry* - Decreases damage taken by the holder from a supereffective Dark-type move
- *Babiri Berry* - Decreases damage taken by the holder from a supereffective Steel-type move
- *Chilan Berry* - Decreases damage taken by the holder from a Normal-type move

Comment: I want Wonder Guard!!!

Comment: @PythonMaster The only pokemon that has it is [Shedinja](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shedinja_(Pok%C3%A9mon)), who makes up for it by having 1 hp.

Comment: I'm having trouble deciding if a few abilities count towards what the question is asking for: **Desolate Land/Primordial Sea**; Cause extreme versions of weather effects that cause damaging Water/Fire moves to fail. **Multitype/Protean/Color Change**; deal with changing the Pokemon's type under certain conditions. This doesn't alter the type advantage chart, but it does change the Pokemon's weaknesses/resistances.

Comment: @TrentHawkins Those sound like they're close enough to what's expected.

Comment: Yeah definitely. I'd say add 'em!

Comment: The berries don't negate the type-effectiveness bonus; they halve the attack's damage. If a Pokemon is quadruply or octuply weak to an attack, it still takes double or quadruple damage.

Comment: Very good, detailed answer! +1!

Comment: @Studoku Have you tried having Mew/Ditto/Smeargle use Transform to change into Shedinja? ;)